# Result on FPGA in Intel DevCloud

Tags: opencl, intel-fpga, intel-oneapi, intel-cloud

I am learning OneAPI OpenCL FPGA implementation in the Intel DevCloud by following this link (https://github.com/intel/FPGA-Devcloud/tree/master/main/QuickStartGuides/OpenCL_Program_PAC_Quicksta...). I am working with MobaXterm on Windows OS. It's a simple 'Hello World' example. I completed every step and everything worked perfectly. It also said 'kernel execution is complete' at the end of the terminal. Now, I would like to see the 'Hello World' result. How am I able to see it in the Intel DevCloud? Thank you.

I am not sure. Aren't I expecting to see a 'Hello World' text on the FPGA in the Intel DevCloud? Please, guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The link provided by you seems to be incomplete. If you are referring to this link: [Stratix 10 PAC: OpenCL Compilation and Programming on the FPGA devcloud using Stratix 10 Devstack version 2.0.1](https://github.com/intel/FPGA-Devcloud/tree/master/main/QuickStartGuides/OpenCL_Program_PAC_Quickstart/Stratix%2010), kindly follow the steps mentioned in the README file in the GitHub repository.

On performing the [Step 3.4](https://github.com/intel/FPGA-Devcloud/tree/master/main/QuickStartGuides/OpenCL_Program_PAC_Quickstart/Stratix%2010#34-downloading-the-bit-stream-into-the-pac-card-and-running-the-host-code), you will get the following output:

```
uXXXX@s005-n006:~/S10_OPENCL_AFU/hello_world$ aocl program acl0 bin/hello_world.aocx
aocl program: Running program from /opt/intel/2.0.1/inteldevstack/d5005_ias_2_0_1_b237/opencl/opencl_bsp/linux64/libexec
Program succeed.

uXXXX@s005-n006:~/S10_OPENCL_AFU/hello_world$ ./bin/host
Querying platform for info:
==========================
CL_PLATFORM_NAME                         = Intel(R) FPGA SDK for OpenCL(TM)
CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR                       = Intel(R) Corporation
CL_PLATFORM_VERSION                      = OpenCL 1.0 Intel(R) FPGA SDK for OpenCL(TM), Version 19.2

Querying device for info:
========================
CL_DEVICE_NAME                           = pac_s10_dc : Intel PAC Platform (pac_f000000)
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR                         = Intel Corp
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID                      = 4466
CL_DEVICE_VERSION                        = OpenCL 1.0 Intel(R) FPGA SDK for OpenCL(TM), Version 19.2
CL_DRIVER_VERSION                        = 19.2
CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS                   = 64
CL_DEVICE_AVAILABLE                      = true
CL_DEVICE_ENDIAN_LITTLE                  = true
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_SIZE          = 32768
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHELINE_SIZE      = 0
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE                = 34359737344
CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT                  = false
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE                 = 16384
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY            = 1000
CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS              = 1
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_ARGS              = 8
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE       = 8589934336
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS       = 3
CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN            = 8192
CL_DEVICE_MIN_DATA_TYPE_ALIGN_SIZE       = 1024
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_CHAR    = 4
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_SHORT   = 2
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_INT     = 1
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG    = 1
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT   = 1
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_DOUBLE  = 0
Command queue out of order?              = false
Command queue profiling enabled?         = true
Using AOCX: hello_world.aocx

Kernel initialization is complete.
Launching the kernel...

Thread #2: Hello from Altera's OpenCL Compiler!

Kernel execution is complete.
```

- The first section under **"Querying platform for info"**, lists the FPGA platform information that is present in the Intel® DevCloud node.
- The second section under **"Querying device for info"** details the FPGA device information. This is only visible if there is a FPGA card installed in the node, otherwise you will get a *CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND* error.
- The line **"Thread #2: Hello from Altera's OpenCL Compiler!"** is the expected output of the program. This is the output that is produced from the FPGA card which is equivalent to Hello World.